# Laurent Series for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^5(1+z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I know that the series for $\frac{1}{1+z}$ are $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nz^n$, so would the Laurent series be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z^5}z^n$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your result is technically correct, but note that $\frac{z^n}{z^5} = z^{n-5}$

Comment: If you are dealing with the Laurent series at the origin, you are correct. $z=0$ is a pole of order $5$ and the Laurent series can be recovered from the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+z}$ at the origin, multiplied by $\frac{1}{z^5}$ (such multiplication just induces a shift on the coefficients).

Comment: Thank you for your comments and yes, I need to obtain the Laurent series  at about $z=0$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio if there is a pole so there shouldn't there be finite element with a negative power? I mean is there a way to "extract them" from the series? or we must write the first elements?